# Somewhat efficient way to append array 1 to array 2, while preserving the numeric keys of array 2, and adding keys n through n + x to array 1?

Tags: php, arrays

This is sort of two questions, but there may be one overall answer for the whole problem. I have an array that I need to append onto another array. Both arrays must have specific numeric keys. My problems are:

1. I need the numeric keys for the array that I am appending onto to be preserved.

   - array_splice() and array_merge() won't work to join the arrays because numeric keys in both arrays will be reset.
2. I need to make the keys of the newly added elements to be n through n + x, meaning if n is 100 and x is 25, the keys for the newly added elements should be 100 through 125.

Can anyone think of a somewhat efficient way of doing this?

**EDIT**

For anyone curious, found a better way of adding the correct keys to the array.

```
// add correct keys
$array_segment = array_combine(range($offset, $offset + count($array_segment) - 1), $array_segment);
// merge arrays while maintaining keys
$first_array = $first_array + $array_segment;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a **very simple** solution but, if I understand well what you want, it works and it's fast. In my opinion you can use this approach:

```
$array1 = array(1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c');
$array2 = array(4 => 'd', 5 => 'e', 6 => 'f');

foreach($array2 as $key => $value)
   $array1[$key] = $value;

var_dump($array1);

$array1[] = 'g';
$array1[] = 'h';

var_dump($array1);
```

You can see the result here:

http://codepad.org/ogD9drpK

Another way which will avoid the foreach is to execute this instruction:

```
// avoid the loop
//foreach($array2 as $key => $value)
//   $array1[$key] = $value;
$array1 += $array2;
```

You can see the result here:

http://codepad.org/cZxCfRn6

Comment: hmm nice answer. not excited about the idea of having to cycle through the array that is to be appended, but this is definitely my fallback.

Comment: Doesn't the OP want the keys to continue from where the keys end on the first array even if the keys of the original arrays overlap? The only reason it works in this example is that the second array starts out with keys that do not need to be altered.. I would change `$array1[$key] = $value;` to `$array1[] = $value;`.

Comment: @ghbarratt As I understand (and it seems it's confirmed by his answer), he want that the number continue from the second array keys (at least as I understand).

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa adding two arrays with a + will destroy all numeric keys.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa also, the appended array could be any segment of numbers. for instance the original array could have keys 25-50, and then I may want to append an array with keys 300-325. so the final array would have keys 25-50 then 300-325.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa Ah for some reason I thought I had read that numeric keys get destroyed as in a merge. thanks for the tip. now if only i could get the keys in the appended array set to how I want without cycling

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa the join will work, but how will i set the keys to be n through n + x in the first place for the appended array?

Comment: only way i can think is to cycle through

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa see edit for better way of adding correct keys to appended array.